# HTML5 video not playing on tablets

Tags: html

Good afternoon,  I posted something on this earlier but am still in need of help.  I have a Nexus 7 and an IPad2.  I have an mp4 file that is encoded H.264.  I use the folowing tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <video controls="controls">
        <source src="Test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

When I go to the webpage on my iPad2 it shows a play button with a line crossing it out.  When I go to teh webpage on my nexus 7 I get the play controls but when I hit play the pause button appears but nothing plays.  It's just a black screen.  I open the same website on a PC or Mac and the video is there and plays just fine without issue.  As a test on my device I went to the example that is on W3Schools for the video tag and load the example.  the example plays just fine on my iPad2 and nexus 7.

I am at a complete loss as to my video will not play on the tablet but works fine on the PC and Mac.  If anyone knows please help me.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: This seems more like a problem with the tablet or its browser compatibility than it does a programming problem.

Comment: I only wonder if it's a programming problem if thevideo plays off other W3Schools site and not mine.  I wonder if I am missing something with the encoding.  I mean how could it be the same issue on two devices?  Leaves me to think I'm missing something with the HTML5 tag or the encoding.

Comment: @seroth: Probably encoding if this is the same HTML.

Comment: What do you see when you View/Source the site that works?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <video controls="controls">
        <source src="Test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: @0A0D: could encoding allow it to play on desktops but not mobile?  If so what should be the encoding settings please?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: I don't understand.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Erm... Did you View/Source the site that worked, or the site that *didn't* work?

Comment: I view sourced the site that works.  It's just base code for video in there.  The site that didn't work and teh site that works source pages both say the same thing.

Comment: plus, I can't view source on a tablet come to think of it.  If I can then can you instruct me on how pls?

Comment: That should work fine. can you post the real HTML and video somewhere so we could look at it. I'm guessing that it's an encoding issue and either the video or audio profile is upsetting the Nexus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be a firewall setting set to a certain folder on my network.  Once I placed the code outside of that folder everything worked fine.